# Select highest date from different columns in a row in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with lot of dates and also null values in data columns. How do I find the greatest among them?

The table name is JOB_DATE_VALUES. The columns are JOB_START_DT, JOB_END_DT, JOB_PROMO_DT, JOB_DEMO_DT for employees in different branches. I need to find the maximum date for the employee in a specific branch. The table is below

```
ROW_ID EMP_NM DEPT_NM JOB_START_DT JOB_END_DT JOB_PROMO_DT JOB_DEMO_DT
1-E4   123   SALES    11-NOV-2014             10-OCT-2015  
1-E5   234   FIN      01-JAN-2013             01-JAN-2015
```

I used LEAST, GREATEST and they return just NULL values. So, please let me know.

Comment: what's the expected result?

Comment: @vkp I need to get the greatest date among the available dates for an employee per branch.

Comment: If the author didn't show what was tried, why do you assume they tried anything? Either ask for a specific bit of information, suggest a specific improvement, or downvote and move on.

Comment: @DennyMueller - What if the author **did** show what was tried? Read the last sentence of the message (and note, also, that it has been there from the outset - there have been no edits to it). The OP tried the right functions, GREATEST and LEAST - and found out that they return NULL if at least one of the arguments is NULL. Which is different from the behavior of MAX and MIN. And they are asking for help. What is your problem with that?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `greatest` substituting `null` values.

```
select greatest(
 nvl(to_date(JOB_START_DT,'DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('01-01-1900','DD-MM-YYYY'))
,nvl(to_date(JOB_END_DT,'DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('01-01-1900','DD-MM-YYYY'))
,nvl(to_date(JOB_PROMO_DT,'DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('01-01-1900','DD-MM-YYYY'))
,nvl(to_date(JOB_DEMO_DT,'DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('01-01-1900','DD-MM-YYYY'))
) as grtst_date
from tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

To manage Null values, you can use the COALESCE expression which is a syntactic shortcut for the CASE expression:

```
GREATEST(
    COALESCE(JOB_START_DT, JOB_END_DT, JOB_PROMO_D, JOB_DEMO_DT),
    COALESCE(JOB_END_DT, JOB_PROMO_D, JOB_DEMO_DT, JOB_START_DT),
    COALESCE(JOB_PROMO_D, JOB_DEMO_DT, JOB_START_DT, JOB_END_DT),
    COALESCE(JOB_DEMO_DT, JOB_START_DT, JOB_END_DT, JOB_PROMO_D)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know (or as you found out with this exercise), LEAST and GREATEST do not work the same way as MIN and MAX. They seem to do the same thing, for values in a row rather than a column. But MIN and MAX ignore nulls, while LEAST and GREATEST do not.

One way to take advantage of MIN and MAX (instead of LEAST and GREATEST) is to UNPIVOT the base table, and then to use standard aggregation. WARNING though: the data in the base table is already "grouped by" row id. By unpivoting, you lose that information, and Oracle needs to group again as if the data wasn't grouped already.

```
select row_id, emp_nm, dept_nm, max(dt) as most_recent_date
from   job_date_values
unpivot ( dt for descr in (job_start_dt, job_end_dt, job_promo_dt, job_demo_dt))
group by row_id, emp_nm, dept_nm
;

ROW_  EMP_NM  DEPT_NM  MOST_RECENT_DATE
----  ------  -------  ----------------
1-E4     123  SALES    10-OCT-2015     
1-E5     234  FIN      01-JAN-2015
```

One advantage of this approach, though, is that you can also include the type of date that is the most recent (is it the job_start_date? job_promo_date? etc.) You can do that by adding to the SELECT clause:

```
select row_id, ... , ... as most recent_date, 
       max(descr) keep (dense_rank last order by dt) as descr
```